# RecyclerView inside ScrollView scrolling issue for Complex data set

Tags: android, xml

Multiple **RecyclerView** has been used inside a **ScrollView**, and when loading data set from the server, the scrolling of RecyclerView is not smooth.

Data set likely heterogeneous list, so I tried heterogeneous RecyclerView; however, there is some issue. So please help me to find out why this was happening through my primary suspect is loading lots of images in UI and complexity of UI.

Even click event of Child **RecyclerView's** Item not working.

```xml
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#11180e"
        tools:context="com.dodock.footylightx.android.controller.livescoredetails.lineups.LineupsFragment">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!--android:weightSum="2"-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#385401"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
    
                <TextView
                    style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/home_team_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
    
                <TextView
                    style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/home_team_formation"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
    
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:id="@+id/line_up_local_team_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_local_field" />
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
    
    
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/line_up_visitor_team_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_visitor_field" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#385401"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
    
                <TextView
                    style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/away_team_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
    
                <TextView
                    style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/away_team_formation"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
    
            <TextView
    
                style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/lineup_textview_bg"
                android:text="Bench"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
    
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/substitution_home_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#385401" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
   
    
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I guess that a simple "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Os Position:"+position + 
            " Select Os :"+osList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); " would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Os Position:"+position,
                    "Select Os :"+parent.getAdapter().getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Also can be needed some modification on parent.getAdapter().getItem(position) depends what this method return for your concrete adapter.

**Update**
This must return data used in your adapter. For example if you use ArrayAdapter with Strings values it must return String.

```
parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

Comment: Instead of saying "Try this <some code>", you should explain what you have done differently and *why* the OP should try that.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the "," with a "+". That's how you concatenate in Java. Otherwise, you are telling it to take an extra `param` and rendering the `makeText()` function invalid

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Os Position:" + position +
        "Select Os :"+osList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In the future, please explain the issue you are having including any error/exception messages.

Comment: Yeah, as there is no any `makeText()` method with four arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code. As mentioned in the answers you are using , instead of + for concatenation. The below code will work.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Os Position:"+position+"Select Os :"+osList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```